# Why some of Asp.Net MVC4 Templates need System.Spatial package?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nuget, spatial, nuget-package

Asp.Net MVC4 templates of Internet and Intranet needs [System.Spatial nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/System.Spatial/)?

```
<package id="System.Spatial" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

This package is about [geospatial data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh525394%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). Why any web framework needs this? Is there any plausible reason for its inclusion in Asp.Net MVC4 templates?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course a generic web framework like the ASP.NET MVC does not need geospatial data types.

However for convenience reasons the templates may include some optional packages like in the this case the Microsoft [ASP.NET Web API OData](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData/4.0.1) package (which as the name implies provides OData support for Web API endpoints) which uses the [Microsoft.Data.OData](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.OData/) which has support for spatial types so it depends on `System.Spatial`

See also on this [package visualizer](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/package-visualizer) generated dependency graph fragment:

[image]